# How to display names of IntEnums in Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, enums

I have an IntEnum which I am using for column names in a pandas dataframe.  I want the names of the enum to display rather then the integer values, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I figured pandas would use the `__format__` method for display, so I tried monkey patching the method of my IntEnum but no dice.  Is this possible?

Comment: What is the dtype of the enum column?  I wonder if `.astype('category')` would work?  Or perhaps `.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories=[e.name for e in MyEnum]))`?

Comment: @0x5453, this seems like it is on the right track.  I can get IntEnums in a Series to display the way I want by setting dtype=object and monkey patching the __format__

pd.Series([Colors.blue, Colors.red], dtype=object)

But I can't seem to accomplish that for column names, even if I pass the type cast series as the coluns argument.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a more fundamental issue in Pandas which is being tracked with Issue [#36124](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/36124).  I will post an update to this question if and when a PR to address gets merged.